# Auto sort photos and videos in folders based on date

Tags: windows, archiving, photos

I am using windows. I have a lot of photos and videos that I want to be sorted in the following structure based on the date of the photo and video taken.

```
year>month>photo.jpg
```

So an example would be

```
2020/
  ├─ 01/
     ├─ pic1.jpg
  ├─ 02/
  │  ├─ pic1.jpg
  │  ├─ pic2.jpg
```

IMPORTANT: One I want is that if there are duplicate files then the file should be renamed rather than overwritten. As the files will be sorted from one folder I don't think there will be any duplicates.

If there is no exif data then the files should be left unsorted.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you look deep into the options that `Exiftool` https://exiftool.org/ has...

Just a glimpse of what I have in use since a number of years:

```
todir='/ImageStore/%Y/%Y-%m-%d/RAW/%Y-%m-%d_%Hh%Mm%Ss';

exiftool -v -r -ext JPG -ext NEF -ext TIF -ext PNG -d "$todir"\
 '-filename<${createdate}\
 _${model;tr/ /_/}\
 -${ShutterCount;s/^.*(....)$/$1/}\
 .${filetypeextension}'\
 "$dir"
```

`todir` is a template to where the images end up.
Exiftool will perform a 'rename' (with implied MOVE of the files present in `$dir`)
to a new filename is based on image creation date, appended with camera model and the last four digits if it's shuttercount.

Now this the basic portions of my bash script, which will not work for you ;-) - so take it as a starting point from where to create your own.